# What can you see, while you are blinking?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

This is easy, right? No, I'm not darkness. Blink, Blink, Blink.... Can you see me? No? Blink again, and tell me what you see. Nothing? Wow, you think it's that easy? No, it's surely not. And if you try being funny... I don't mean the inside of your eyelids neither. Blink and think... blink and think... Tick tack, think faster, my time is not endless....

**Hint**

Think about the last sentence

Comment: Tick, tack, I can just see time passing by. Maybe I'm not an expert in lateral-thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a

> Transition
> When you go from seeing to not seeing, or from open eyes to closed eyes?

Comment: I don't get the link with the blinking part. Is it really the expected answer?

Comment: So it is a Transition, wow.

Answer (score 14):

Well the only thing fitting the description seems to be

> Afterimage

Comment: Good answer, definitely makes sense in light of the hint provided.

Answer (score 8):

Is it...

> **EYELASHES**
>
>  Given that they curve towards the iris slightly, when blinking they'd come in the path of vision:
>  [image]
>  <sub>Image courtesy https://investingcaffeine.com/2010/01/14/google-vs-china-running-away-from-660-million-eyeballs/</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Well i guess that the answer is:

> I can see the Puzzling.se site while blinking presently. I can see that the glimpse of answer is being typed and earlier while blinking I saw the glimpse of question in front of my eyes. I posted this answer since there is a lateral-thinking tag in the question.

Answer (score 4):

If the title didn't say "while *you* are blinking" I'd think it might be

> a flashing green man/crossing signal, indicating that your time to cross the road is short and you should decide quickly ("think faster") if you want to do so

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Light?
>  Blink is also defined as "a momentary gleam of light" which we can still see (through our eyelids) while we're blinking.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks a bit like:

> a Morse code
>  "blink blink blink" "blink" "blink think""blink think"
>  which translates to
>  ... . .- .-
>  which in turns is  s e a a
>  which unfortunately doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

> An Afterimage?
> Persistence of vision would leave you looking at a brief afterimage, whose time would not be endless.

Apologies to Oleksii - I didn't see that this answer was already in the list.

Comment: This answer was already given.

Comment: Believe it or not, I didn't see that one - no pun intended. :)

Comment: (I believe you, but independent work doesn't salvage a duplicate answer posted hours later. Unless you can edit this answer to meaningfully differentiate it somehow from the one already given—which, given the simple nature of the answer, seems unlikely—deleting it is probably the best course here. You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.... and on this one, ya got scooped!)

Answer (score 0):

> You see the same thing when you're not blinking.  An interpretation of just a moment ago.  You're never seeing the honest to goodness real moment, it's always a processed, filtered, and delayed reality created by your brain.